# KendoGrid - Filtering on a property of object

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

here is my KendoGrid :

```
    $scope.gridEltCompoOptions = {
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        ...
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: 'IdElement',
                            fields: {
                                GroupeActes: { defaultValue: { IdGroupeActes: null, Libelle: ' ' } }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                sortable: true,
                resizable: true,
                filterable: {
                    mode: 'row'
                },
                columns: [{
                    field: 'GroupeActes',
                    title: "Groupe d'actes",
                    template: function (dataItem) {
                        return kendo.toString(dataItem.GroupeActes.Libelle);
                    }
                }, ]
```

I want to filter my field 'GroupeActes' on the property Libelle (GroupeActes is an object), but actually the filter take the entire object.

When i try to filter, i have a Js Error

> Uncaught TypeError: (d.GroupeActes || "").toLowerCase is not a function

The problem is clear, the filter is taking the entiere object, not the property Libelle.
i passed the last 4 hours to try all the solutions i found on google but nothing is working

my object GroupeActes is like this :
var GroupeActes = {
GroupeActes : {
Libelle : ""
}
}
there is two groupeActes level

I saw a post in 2015 of an Admin, saying this kind of filter isn't possible,
but i saw also this kind of solution :
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-filter-column-with-dropdownlist

(if(e.field == "Category" && e.filter !== null){) in the example
i tried to do something like : if field == "groupeActes" => so i want to filter on Libelle properties,
but i didn't success

Can someone help me please ?

thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this article:  https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/enable-operations-for-object-column

I believe you can accomplish what you want by setting the column field to `"GroupeActes.Libelle"` instead of using a column template:

```
columns: [
    {
        field: 'GroupeActes.Libelle',
        title: "Groupe d'actes",
    }, 
],
```

See this [DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/iZiWaZEF):

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the fact is i need the entire object for my project, i already tried this solution but when i call my server after, i lose all the information of my object

Comment: Actually my field have to be the entire object, and i have to show only the property "Libelle" in my grid (with the template), and the problem is i want to filter on the property Libelle to => but as you know the filter take the object given on the "field:"

Comment: @blackstar012 - could you add a string column just for display and filtering Libelle and then keep the object column hidden?